# Is there a way to access Micrososft 365 Defender Endpoints setting through powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft365-defender, endpoint-for-defender

I would like to access to all the information in the picture below, so all settings in the Micrososft 365 Defender Endpoints via Powershell. Is there a specific command like a Get-...  that I can use to access those information ? If not, is there another way to get this extracted via a script ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkTVS.png)

Tried to use some powershell commands that doesnt give me the expected result

Comment: Se following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/manage-mde-post-migration-other-tools?force_isolation=true&view=o365-worldwide